# Cannot create new user in Single-user mode

Tags: macos, imac, single-user, open-directory

I try to create new user using the following commands:

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
/sbin/mount -uw /
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist
dscl . -create /Users/username
```

But after the last command I get the error `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServicesLocal.plist: No such file or directory`. Actually, I get it on every launch of `dscl` command, even without any arguments. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that this error can be just ignored, because the user is properly created anyway.

Comment: Nice, mark it as solved when possible.